# Qual a finalidade do Middleware em relação a APIs e Aplicações Web feitas no Slim?

Tags: php, http, slim, middleware

Estou [lendo](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html) a respeito de *Middleware* no framework Slim, porém, eu não consegui compreender a finalidade do Middleware em relação a APIs Rest ou Aplicações Web construídas no Slim.

Também estava conversando com o [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) no chat a respeito deste [assunto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37697934#37697934) e ele me disse o seguinte:

> o middleware controla o HTTP todo, digamos que o middleware é um
> manipulador vc pode usar ou deixar rolar, a autenticação do slim entra
> no meio do HTTP do controle do slim e manipula a situação

Esta conversa me gerou mais algumas dúvidas, que eu vou abordar logo abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade do middleware no Framework Slim, na construção de APIs ou Aplicações Web?
2. Qual é a relação que o middleware tem com o protocolo HTTP? E em que
   sentido ele controla o HTTP todo?

<sup>Se for darem exemplos de código, eu gostaria que fosse em PHP.</sup>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As palavras do Guilherme resumem bem o conceito de *middleware*. O *middleware* é uma estrutura para se trabalhar diretamente sobre o protocolo HTTP, tendo como entrada a requisição HTTP recebida pelo servidor e como saída a resposta HTTP gerada. Esta resposta pode, ou não, ser gerada pelo próprio *middleware*. No caso da autenticação, por exemplo, o *middleware* responsável irá verificar as credenciais presentes na requisição; se forem nulas ou inválidas, o próprio *middleware* irá gerar a resposta de acesso negado; mas caso contrário, ele permite que a requisição de propague pela aplicação.

## *Too Long, Read Anyway*

A resposta será longa, mas vale a leitura (valeu para mim, pelo menos).

### Middleware e o protocolo HTTP

O *middleware* trabalha diretamente sobre o protocolo HTTP - de fato, qualquer aplicação WEB que utiliza tal protocolo trabalhará diretamente sobre ele, porém nem sempre é tão franco como cosstuma ser com o *middleware*. Em PHP, isso costuma ficar bem nítido pois os *middlewares* trabalham sobre a recomendação definida na [PSR-7: HTTP Message Interfaces](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/). Esta recomendação define uma interface para as requisições HTTP:

```
Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface
```

Ou, justamente para representar a requisição recebida pelo servidor, a interface (esta interface estende a anterior):

```
Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface
```

Para trabalhar com as respostas HTTP, definiu-se a interface:

```
Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
```

Estas três podem ser consideradas as triviais da PSR-7. As implementações destas interfaces podem ser encontradas no [repositório](https://github.com/php-fig/http-message) oficial da PSR e instaladas no projeto através do Composer:

```
composer install psr/http-message
```

Em particular, o *framework* Slim utiliza estas interfaces. Para confirmar, basta verificar as implementações das classes [`Request`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/Request.php) e [`Response`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php):

Request.php:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

class Request extends Message implements ServerRequestInterface {}
```

Response.php:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class Response extends Message implements ResponseInterface {}
```

Então, a partir deste momento, quando referido-se a um objeto `Request` entenda-se por um objeto que implementa a interface `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface` (ou equivalente), seja do Slim ou não, e quando referido-se a um objeto `Response` entenda-se por um objeto que implementa a interface `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` (ou equivalente), seja do Slim ou não.

### Implementação de um middleware

Desta forma, então, fica mais claro quais são as entradas e saídas de um *middleware*: um objeto `Request` de entrada (`$request`) e um objeto `Response` de saída (`$response`). Existe uma nova PSR que trata apenas sobre *middlewares*: a [PSR-10](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/http-middleware/middleware.md), porém esta recomendação ainda está em fase de rascunho e pode sofrer alterações, embora já possua uma estrutura bem consolidada e aplicada em alguns *frameworks*.

De forma simplificada, existem 3 maneiras distintas de se implementar um *middleware*:

#### 1. *Double Pass*

Esta abordagem é, atualmente, a mais utilizada e foi baseada no *framework* Express:

```
function(request, response, next): response
```

Nesta abordagem, podemos definir que o *middleware* é definido como um objeto `callable` (comumente como Closure), que recebe três parâmetros:

- `request`: um objeto `Request`;
- `response`: um objeto `Response`;
- `next`: um objeto `callable` que representa o próximo *middleware*;

Esta abordagem faz mais sentido quando os *middlewares* são postos em forma de *pipeline*, ou seja, alinhados, em que a saída de um servirá como entrada do outro, explicando o motivo de o objeto `Response` também ser propagado como parâmetro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Figura 1:** Diagrama de blocos representando a organização de *middlewares* alinhados.

Um exemplo desta implementação seria:

```
function auth ($request, $response, $next)
{
    if (! Auth::validate()) {
        $response = new Response(401, "Unauthorized");
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

Perceba que no *middleware* de autenticação é executada a lógica de verificação das credenciais e, caso falhe, a resposta é alterada para uma resposta 401. O problema desta estrutura é que todos os *middlewares* serão executados e aqueles que necessitam de autenticação para serem executados terão que fazer a verificação de qual é a resposta que chegou como parâmetro:

```
function anything ($request, $response, $next)
{
    if ($response->getCode() == 200) {
        // Faça algo apenas se a resposta está OK.
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

Para contornar este problema, algumas aplicações preferem a estrutura de pilhas a alinhada, pois a estrutura de pilha permite o que chamamos de curto-circuito na resposta HTTP. Por exemplo, se o *middleware* de autenticação já gerar uma resposta 401, não há a necessidade de executar o resto da aplicação, então esta resposta é "curto-circuitada" para a saída da aplicação. Para isso, basta modificar levemente o código:

```
function auth ($request, $response, $next)
{
    if (! Auth::validate()) {
        return new Response(401, "Unauthorized");
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

Perceba que ao invés de apenas modificar o objeto `$response`, a nova resposta é retornada, sem ter que executar os próximos *middlewares*, através de `$next`. Desta forma, a representação gráfica fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Figura 2:** Diagrama de blocos representando a organização de *middlewares* em pilha.

Perceba que o objeto `Response` que é enviado à saída é o retorno do primeiro *middleware*, não mais do último, que é o que permite o curto-circuito da resposta.

Projetos que utilizam esta abordagem:

- [mindplay/middleman v1](https://github.com/mindplay-dk/middleman/blob/1.0.0/src/MiddlewareInterface.php#L24)
- [relay/relay v1](https://github.com/relayphp/Relay.Relay/blob/1.0.0/src/MiddlewareInterface.php#L24)
- [slim/slim v3](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.4.0/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php#L66-L75)
- [zendframework/zend-stratigility v1](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stratigility/blob/1.0.0/src/MiddlewarePipe.php#L69-L79)

#### 2. Single Pass

A abordagem *single pass* é bem parecida com a *double pass*, diferindo apenas que o objeto `Response` não é passado como parâmetro:

```
function(request, next): response
```

Nesta abordagem, podemos definir que o *middleware* é definido como um objeto `callable` (comumente como Closure), que recebe dois parâmetros:

- `request`: um objeto `Request`;
- `next`: um objeto `callable` que representa o próximo *middleware*;

Desta forma, cada *middleware* não tem acesso à resposta HTTP até que uma seja gerada pela aplicação, em *middlewares* mais internos. Isto é, nesta abordagem, somente é possível a estrutura em pilhas (Figura 2). A técnica de curto-circuito da resposta também pode ser aplicada nesta abordagem.

```
function auth ($request, $next)
{
    if(! Auth::validate())
    {
        return new Response(401, "Unauthorized");
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Projetos que utilizam *single pass*:

- [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html)

> **Nota pessoal:** Eu particularmente acho que faz muito mais sentido a abordagem *single pass* do que a *double pass*, pois, quando utilizado os *middlewares* junto com uma aplicação MVC, espera-se que o controlador gere a resposta final e sendo o *middleware* executado antes do controlador, não haverá uma resposta de entrada.

#### 3. Middleware Interface

A PSR-10 definiu uma terceira abordagem baseada em uma interface para *middlewares*. Esta interface define apenas um método, chamado `process`, com dois parâmetros: o objeto `Request` e um objeto `Delegate`, que representa os próximos *middlewares*. Como tal PSR ainda está em fase de rascunho, não há uma implementação *oficial*, então colocarei a minha como exemplo:

```php
interface Middleware
{
    /**
     * Processa uma requisição HTTP de entrada e retorna uma resposta.
     * 
     * O middleware é responsável por fazer o tratamento da requisição HTTP de
     * entrada e retornar uma resposta. A resposta pode ser gerada pelo
     * middleware ou o mesmo pode delegar o retorno ao próximo middleware da
     * lista, através do objeto `$delegate`. Para o primeiro caso, quando o
     * middleware gera a resposta retornada, todos os middlewares restantes na
     * lista serão ignorados pela aplicação.
     *
     * @param Request $request Requisição a ser tratada pelo middleware. 
     * @param Delegate $delegate Instância de Delegate que controla os middlewares.
     * @return Response Resposta gerada pelo middleware.
     */
    public function process($request, $delegate);
}
```

Alguns comentários sobre esta abordagem:

**Por quê não utilizar o método __invoke?**

Nas abordagens anteriores, *double pass* e *single pass*, como os *middlewares* são definidos como *closures*, os mesmos podem ser implementados através de classes utilizando o método `__invoke`, então a abordagem definida na PSR-10 optou por não utilizá-lo para não gerar conflitos e manter a *forwards compatibility*.

**Por quê utilizar o nome `process` para o método?**

Algumas outras estruturas já existentes, principalmente relacionadas à arquitetura MVC, já possuem nomes semelhantes, tais como: `__invoke`, como supracitado, `handle`, como utilizado no `HttpKernel` do Symfony, e `dispatch`, como utilizado no `DispatchableInterface` do Zend. Para não gerar conflito ou confusão com estas estruturas, optou-se pelo nome `process`.

Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados direto na PSR-10, porém, para simplificar, o objeto `Delegate` deve possuir pelo menos o método `process`, que é análogo ao funcionamento do `$next` nas abordagens anteriores. Um exemplo de *middleware* nesta abordagem seria:

```
class AuthMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    public function process($request, $delegate)
    {
        if (! Auth::validate()) {
            return new Response(401, "Unauthorized");
        }

        return $delegate->process($request);
    }
}
```

A representação gráfica desta abordagem é igual a da abordagem *single pass*, ilustrada na figura 2, portanto, também é permitido á técnica de curto-circuito da resposta, como apresentado no código acima.

### Middleware e aplicações MVC

A grande maioria dos *frameworks* que utilizam o conceito de *middleware* já utilizavam a arquitetura MVC antes, então atualmente eles unem os dois conceitos, definindo os *middlewares* como componentes plugáveis à aplicação - isto é, você pode adicionar ou remover sem ter que modificar a lógica da sua aplicação em si. O Slim é um exemplo disso: utiliza a abordagem *double pass* em forma de pilha e centraliza a aplicação MVC no interior da mesma, como na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Figura 3:** Ilustração de como funciona a interação entre *middlewares* e aplicações MVC na grande maioria dos casos.

Superficialmente, podemos entender a aplicação MVC como um grande *middleware*, pois a entrada do mesmo é uma requisição HTTP e ele gera uma resposta adequada. O conceito de *middleware*, de fato, serve para delegar tarefas distintas à estruturas distintas. Por exemplo, a arquitetura MVC consegue criar um contexto para se trabalhar com rotas bem diversificadas, executando determinados controladores para cada rota existente, mas se for implementar regras de autenticação, controle de cachê, etc, a lógica do controlador começa a complicar em forma exponencial. Com o conceito de *middleware* você pode delegar a aplicação MVC fazer aquilo que ela faz melhor e delegar as lógicas de autenticação e controle de cachê a estruturas adaptadas para isso: os *middlewares*.