# O que é e para que serve um middleware?

Tags: terminologia, middleware

Vejo em alguns cursos algumas pessoas destacarem algo como um middleware, **exemplo**: middleware(*autenticação, autorização*).
Achei a explicação bastante superficial até porque não era foco do curso, acabei não entendendo muito bem o que é um middleware.

- Afinal o que é um middleware?
- Quais são os tipos de middleware existentes?
- Para que serve?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a finalidade do Middleware em relação a APIs e Aplicações Web feitas no Slim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208114/5878)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Afinal o que é um middleware? Para que serve?

Bom, podemos responder essas duas perguntas juntas: um *middleware* é, dizendo em termos muito simples ***uma camada no meio*** de duas aplicações, ou seja, uma camada que ajuda duas aplicações, partes, sistemas, a se comunicarem.

Serve para facilitar ou tornar viável essa comunicação. Pensamos em  interfaces, converter dados e formatos, prover protocolos, dentre outros.

Serve então para prover ou facilitar o a comunicação entre duas aplicações, que podem ser de plataformas diferentes e tecnologias diferentes.

Uma imagem interessante que ilustra isso, é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Is-an-API-considered-middleware](https://www.quora.com/Is-an-API-considered-middleware)

O interessante dessa imagem é que ela mostra uma *API* como um *middleware*, ou seja, fornece uma camada intermediária para a comunicação, por exemplo, entre um serviço da empresa e um usuário externo.
Veja, aqui está apenas ilustrando, como exemplo, uma API funcionando como um *middleware*, mas ambos são coisas distintas.

## Quais são os tipos de middleware existentes?

Não há uma definição clara sobre quais os tipos de *middleware*, já li a respeito e cada fonte tem uma definição. Não pensando em tipos mas, em onde são mais comuns esses tipos de aplicação, poderíamos elencar:

- Sistemas Operacionais: são os *middlewares* usados na comunicação
  do *core* de um SO e os aplicativos que o executam (serviços,
  drivers, DLLs).
- Sistemas distribuídos: onde aplicativos fornecem as interfaces de
  comunicação entre diferentes sistemas (API, ESB, ODBC, OLEDB) fazendo
  o papel de *middleware*.
- Equipamentos: principalmente com o surgimento da **IoT** (Internet
  das coisas), onde os equipamentos precisam utilizar uma camada para
  se comunicar com outros equipamentos e sistemas, os *middleware*
  estão com certeza presentes.

<sup>[O que é middleware?](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/overview/what-is-middleware/)</sup>

<sup>[O que é middleware?](https://www.redhat.com/pt-br/topics/middleware/what-is-middleware)</sup>

Comment: Frisando que Middlewares só existem devido a problemas de integração. Como é difícil garantir interoperabilidade é necessário usar desses artifícios de integração na indústria. Mas o melhor mesmo é evitá-los, porque geram um trabalho imenso de manutenção. O ideal mesmo é usar uma arquitetura como SOA que preserva a interoperabilidade dos sistemas ao máximo.

Comment: Sim, o propósito deles é resolver problemas de integração, mas nem sempre é possível implantar uma arquitetura SOA, principalmente ser for uma aplicação pequena, dai microserviços e outros tipos de interfaces podem ser uma boa ideia, além claro dos middlewares

Comment: Valeu @RicardoPontual, dei só um estilizadinha na reposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Vamos pensar como funciona o **lifecycle** de uma requisição. Toda vez que uma request chega, ela precisa ser resolvida. E pra resolvê-la chamamos um controller que contém uma regra de negócio e no fim respondemos essa requisição (Request -> Controller -> Response).

E um **middleware** serve para mudar essa história. Antes da request chegar no controller, ela é interceptada por nossos middlewares (plural pois é possível ter vários). Então a request passa chega e passa pelos middlewares para só então chegar no controller (Request -> Middlewares -> Controller -> Response).

## E para que serve um middleware?

Bom, serve para duas coisas:

1. Manipular os objetos de REQUEST e RESPONSE (injetar propriedades, deletar, editar etc... De forma que fique disponível em todos os controllers da aplicação). Ou, então, ter um controle minuscioso, por exemplo: Eu quero que um middleware execute apenas para um grupo de rotas ou rota específica.
2. Controlar o lifecycle. Por exemplo, dentro de um middleware eu posso dizer se a request deve continuar passando (ir para controller, executar a regra de negócio e responder) ou se a request deve parar no próprio middleware (Reques <-> Middlewares -> Controller -> Response).
   Ou seja, o middleware consege responder a requisição antes mesmo de chamar o controller. Um exemplo disso é um middleware para autenticação, então ao invés de fazer a validação de um token JWT dentro de um controller que vai resolver as rotas que serão autenticadas, criamos um middleware e verificamos isso lá mesmo.